# Algolia show array values with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, algolia

So I'm using Algolia's instant search and am loving it, but I'm having one issue. My database model has a polymorphic assocation where each `tag` is stored in an array, and I want to simply display all the tags as one string, but I don't know how to do that. I've tried getting tag_list.value, but that didn't work, and everything else becomes undefined.

```
<script>
var client = algoliasearch("xxxxx", "xxxx");
var index = client.initIndex('myname');
//initialize autocomplete on search input (ID selector must match)
autocomplete('#aa-search-input',
{ hint: false }, {
    source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, {hitsPerPage: 25}),
    //value to be displayed in input control after user's suggestion selection
    displayKey: 'name',
    //hash of templates used when rendering dataset
    templates: {
        //'suggestion' templating function used to render a single suggestion
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return '<span class="aa-highlight">' +
            suggestion._highlightResult.tag_list.value +
            suggestion._highlightResult.question.value + '</span><span>' +
            suggestion._highlightResult.answer_explanation.value + '</span>';
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

tag_list is an array, but i don't know how to access the json array in javascript is what i'm asking. I tried .stringify  and .arr[0], but those were undefinde.

```
        suggestion._highlightResult.tag_list.value +
```

This is the code / line of code in question that i'm having trouble with.

Comment: You can inspect the variable using your browser's developer tools. Add a breakpoint somewhere when suggestion is already defined and you should be able to inspect all it's content to see which keys you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on arieljuod's comment, it would help to know what type `suggestion._highlightResult.tag_list.value` is returning. That being said, I hope the following will help.

## Array to string

In JavaScript you can convert an array to a string by calling the [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method on the array.

#### Examples

**Single-item Array**

```
var array = ["item 1"];
array.join(); // Output: "item 1"
```

**Mult-item Array**

```
var array = ["item 1", "item 2"];
array.join(); // Output: "item 1,item 2"
```

**Custom separator**

By default, the `join` method uses "," as the separator for each item in the array. If you'd like to use something different then you can pass a string to the `join` function:

```
var array = ["item 1", "item 2"];
array.join("/"); // Output: "item 1/item 2"
```

## JSON array to JavaScript array

I'm including this because I'm not sure what data type is being returned from `suggestion._highlightResult.tag_list.value`.

If the value returned from `tag_list.value` is a string containing JSON (i.e. `"[\"item 1\", \"item 2\"]"` then you can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it into a JavaScript array:

```
var json_string = "[\"item 1\", \"item 2\"]";
JSON.parse(json_string); // Output: ["item 1", "item 2"]
```